# Stopping events / functions from firing when using angular-gantt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this angular directive [angular-gantt](https://github.com/Schweigi/angular-gantt%22Angular-Gantt%22).  it creates a gantt chart display tasks.  You can set a number of options, the relevant ones here are on-row-clicked, on-task-clicked and on-task-updated.

My problem is that when I update a task(resize or move) the on-task-updated event fires and then the on-task-clicked event fires.  I want to stop after the first event.

I have tried adding $event.stopPropagation() to the beginning of the function that on-task-updated is calling but that dosn't work.  I have also tried adding it to the tasks ng-click like so

```
ng-click="raiseDOMTaskClickedEvent($event, task); $event.stopPropagation();"
```

but similarly that did not work.

the code from the directive that calls my functions for me should be this

```
$scope.raiseTaskClickedEvent = function(task) {
      $scope.onTaskClicked({ event: { task: task } });
};

$scope.raiseTaskUpdatedEvent = function(task) {
      $scope.onTaskUpdated({ event: { task: task } });
};
```

I am guessing that the there are two listeners being added one for clicked and one for updated and they are both firing at the same time or very close together but I dont know how to troubleshoot something like that

Answer (score 0):

try to do this on `ng-mouseup` and use `stoppropagation`